# deploy Open Source CMS 'my little forum' on Cloud Foundry (requires PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, web-deployment, cloud-foundry, buildpack

> my little forum is a simple PHP and MySQL based internet forum that
>   displays the messages in classical threaded view (tree structure). It
>   is Open Source licensed under the GNU General Public License. The main
>   claim of this web forum is simplicity. Furthermore it should be easy
>   to install and run on a standard server configuration with PHP and
>   MySQL.

I tried to deploy [mylittleforum](https://github.com/ilosuna/mylittleforum) on Cloud Foundry based hosting.

> Installation
>
> Unzip the script package. 
>   Upload the complete folder "forum" to yourserver.
>
> Depending on your server configuration the write permissions of the
>   subdirectory templates_c (CHMOD 770, 775 or 777) and the file
>   config/db_settings.php (CHMOD 666) might need to be changed in order
>   that they are writable by the script. Run the installation script by
>   accessing yourdomain.tld/forum/install/ in your web browser and follow
>   the instructions.

What I did:

```
wget -nd https://github.com/ilosuna/mylittleforum/archive/v2.3.5.tar.gz
tar xvfz v2.3.5.tar.gz
cd mylittleforum-2.3.5/
cf cs mariadb large mylittleforum-db
cf push mylittleforum -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
cf bs mylittleforum mylittleforum-db
cf env mylittleforum
vi config/db_settings.php 
<?php
// Database host, mostly 'localhost':
$db_settings['host'] = '10.0.20.18';

// Database name:
$db_settings['database'] = 'CF_39CC64E1_578D_IIF3_BF1F_BC06LDIDK74009';

// Database user name:
$db_settings['user'] = '84mwzL9fonrlptzmGn';

// Database password:
$db_settings['password'] = 'xzG1s0dff89lYtunp5Mn';

// Database tables (normally not necessary to edit): 
$db_settings['settings_table'] =       'mlf2_settings';
$db_settings['forum_table'] =          'mlf2_entries';
$db_settings['category_table'] =       'mlf2_categories';
$db_settings['userdata_table'] =       'mlf2_userdata';
$db_settings['smilies_table'] =        'mlf2_smilies';
$db_settings['pages_table'] =          'mlf2_pages';
$db_settings['banlists_table'] =       'mlf2_banlists';
$db_settings['useronline_table'] =     'mlf2_useronline';
$db_settings['login_control_table'] =  'mlf2_logincontrol';
$db_settings['entry_cache_table'] =    'mlf2_entries_cache';
$db_settings['userdata_cache_table'] = 'mlf2_userdata_cache';
?>
chmod 777 config/db_settings.php
cf push mylittleforum -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
```

Then tried to start the installer, but received 404. Update found out that the installer located in http://mylittleforum.domain/install/

```
curl -I http://mylittleforum.domain/forum/install/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2016 19:03:25 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Vcap-Request-Id: bd734b38-bb6e-4167-731c-f20d8aabfb51
```

CF Push output

```
$ cf push mylittleforum -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
Updating app mylittleforum in org xxx / space xxx as xxx...
OK

Uploading mylittleforum...
Uploading app files from: /Users/xxx/Downloads/mylittleforum-2.3.5
Uploading 2M, 405 files
Done uploading               
OK

Stopping app mylittleforum in org xxx / space xxx as xxx...
OK

Starting app mylittleforum in org xxx / space xxx as xxx...
Creating container
Successfully created container
Downloading app package...
Downloaded app package (1008.5K)
Downloading build artifacts cache...
Downloaded build artifacts cache (109B)
Staging...
-------> Buildpack version 4.3.17
Installing HTTPD
Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/concourse-binaries/httpd/httpd-2.4.23-linux-x64.tgz] to [/tmp]
Installing PHP
PHP 5.5.37
Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/concourse-binaries/php/php-5.5.37-linux-x64-1468353118.tgz] to [/tmp]
Finished: [2016-07-29 19:16:32.177909]
Exit status 0
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (109B)
Uploaded droplet (48.3M)
Uploading complete

1 of 1 instances running

App started


OK

App mylittleforum was started using this command `$HOME/.bp/bin/start`

Showing health and status for app mylittleforum in org xxx / space xxx as xxx...
OK

requested state: started
instances: 1/1
usage: 1G x 1 instances
urls: mylittleforum.domain
last uploaded: Fri Jul 29 19:16:18 UTC 2016
stack: cflinuxfs2
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git

     state     since                    cpu    memory        disk           details
#0   running   2016-07-29 09:16:51 PM   0.5%   22.7M of 1G   142.6M of 1G
```

PHP Buildpack options (`.bp-config/options.json`)

```
$ pwd
/Users/RomeoOw/Downloads/mylittleforum-2.3.5
$ cat .bp-config/options.json 
{
    "WEBDIR": ""
}
```

I ssh into container (after delete app and push again, it's strange timestamps, I guess because of S3 file caching):

```
$ cf ssh mylittleforum
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~$ pwd
/home/vcap
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~$ ls -al
total 36
drwx------  6 vcap vcap 4096 Jul 31 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 31 14:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 19 vcap root 4096 Jul 31 14:19 app
-rw-r--r--  1 vcap vcap  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 vcap vcap 3637 Apr  9  2014 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 vcap vcap 4096 Jul 31 14:19 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 vcap vcap  675 Apr  9  2014 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1 vcap vcap   64 Jul 31 14:19 staging_info.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 vcap vcap 4096 Jul 31 14:22 tmp
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~$ cd app/
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~/app$ ls -lrt
total 124
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap  1158 Jul 31 14:19 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap 33093 Jul 31 14:19 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap  7757 Jul 31 14:19 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap 17047 Jul 31 14:19 CHANGELOG
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 update
drwxr-xr-x 3 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 templates_c
drwxr-xr-x 8 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 modules
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 lang
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 js
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 install
drwxr-xr-x 3 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 includes
drwxr-xr-x 5 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 backup
drwxr-xr-x 7 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 httpd
drwxr-xr-x 8 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:19 php
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jul 31 14:20 logs
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~/app$ cd install/
vcap@88b21d94-0a7d-4c7c-74f9-2c1af0b49578:~/app/install$ ls -lrt
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap 12765 Jul 31 14:19 install.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap 21779 Jul 31 14:19 index.php
```

I tried:

```
$ curl -I http://mylittleforum.domain/install/
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 31 Jul 2016 14:27:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Vcap-Request-Id: ab6db4f1-78ff-483e-7b74-09211fd0b6b9
```

This my app logs (I tried both wrong and good paths). Wrong path `/forum/install/` gives 404 and good path `/install/` gives 500. In logs I see not more info than the fact the status code is 500. CF app output seems healthy `mylittleforum   started           1/1         1G       1G     mylittleforum.domain`

I had a look at `app/.bp/logs/bp.log` with `cf ssh`. Nothing useful. After enabling BP debug the logs dir was lost.

```
cf set-env mylittleforum BP_DEBUG true
```

Did a repush and found also no useful info about my request in Safari which results in 500. Before my request there was a lot of debug logs. See the `cf logs --recent` output [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c77747e4c629f004065abfcd1f7f976c/raw/b1e0eb25934a0e5c1bd5f1a8546759b560032d7f/gistfile1.txt)

When I access other URL `/index.php/install/`, there are additional HTTP headers (`Set-Cookie`, `Pragma`, `Expires` and `Cache-Control`)

```
curl -I http://mylittleforum.domain/index.php/install/
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 31 Jul 2016 20:14:56 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: __VCAP_ID__=1334380f-6a6c-400c-62aa-56b07b4044b6; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=fvqr2fe7ac5gd73k24lr8drom7; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Vcap-Request-Id: f4aa004c-87a8-482e-60cd-c5704c6cf9da
```

Comment: The `curl` command most likely tries to execute PHP code (which is good) as it returns a 500 (another cause could be webserver misconfiguration). Is there any hint in `cf logs --recent`?

Comment: Yes, there is not much helpful information in the logs. With the current information it is difficult to pinpoint the failure, however you can try to [troubleshoot the PHP buildpack](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-usage.html#troubleshooting). Let me know if you find something interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any other hint in the new logs. However, I noticed that mylittleforum does not provide a `.htaccess` configuring mod_rewrite, so try to check how the buildpack sets that up. Also, try to access http://mylittleforum.domain/index.php/install/ to see if that might work (might if mod_rewrite is not properly configured).

Answer (score 1):

**Set WEBDIR in buildpack options:**

It seems the buildpack tries to serve the folder defined in the `WEBDIR` variable of the buildpack config, which defaults to `htdocs`. mylittleforum expects the files to be served from the root of the project, so try [changing the buildpack option](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html) value to an empty string.

**Fetch config from environment:**

Apart from that, I recommend you to set the `config/db_settings.php` by fetching the respective environment variables using the `phpenv()` ([see manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getenv.php)) function.